# sqlalchemy one to many relationship and adding to data base

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login

hi there hope yu will be able to help me.

im trying to add a post to a blog, now im trying to fetch the name of the user so it
will be diplayed on the site.

```
def add_new_post():
form = CreatePostForm()
if request.method == 'POST':
    user_data = User.query.filter_by(id=current_user.id).first()
    user_name_to_post = str(user_data.name)
    print(current_user.name)
    new_post = BlogPost(
        title=form.title.data,
        subtitle=form.subtitle.data,
        body=form.body.data,
        img_url=form.img_url.data,
        author=current_user, <-------------------
        date=date.today().strftime("%B %d, %Y")
    )
    db.session.add(new_post)
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect(url_for("get_all_posts"))
return render_template("make-post.html", form=form, is_active=current_user.is_active)
```

now as long the author=current_user, it works but it displays "user1"
as the author name on the site.

if im trying to put the name it raise an exaption

```
new_post = BlogPost(
        title=form.title.data,
        subtitle=form.subtitle.data,
        body=form.body.data,
        img_url=form.img_url.data,
        author=current_user.name, <------------------
        date=date.today().strftime("%B %d, %Y")
```

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'

i have tried to go more direct into the user and did this idea that i read somewhere.

```
new_post = BlogPost(
        title=form.title.data,
        subtitle=form.subtitle.data,
        body=form.body.data,
        img_url=form.img_url.data,
        author=User(name=current_user.name), <--------------
        date=date.today().strftime("%B %d, %Y")
    )
```

it gives me this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) NOT NULL constraint failed: 
users.email
[SQL: INSERT INTO users (name, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: ('jay ber', None, None)]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/gkpj)

Traceback (most recent call last)
```

my databse looks like that:

```
class BlogPost(db.Model):
__tablename__ = "blog_posts"
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
author = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
title = db.Column(db.String(250), unique=True, nullable=False)
subtitle = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
date = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
body = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
img_url = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
author_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("users.id"))
author = relationship("User", back_populates="posts")

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'users'
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
email = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
password = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
posts = relationship("BlogPost", back_populates="author")
```

i hope some one can help me with it.
all i want is to display the name of the author as part of the blog post

Comment: `author` expects to receive a `User` instance, which is why you get an error if you pass it a string.  You say `user1` is displayed instead of the actual author name on the site - can you share the template code (and the view code, if it isn't the view in the question)?

Comment: first of all thank you very much for the reply :) . I i have found the problem and fixed it. thank you very much